Dependencies problem, github Asana Could not import sentence_transformers python package. Please install it with `pip install sentence-transformers`
just started to learn LangChain and move my project onto langchain.
To keep moving forward i got this github project:
https://github.com/Cbase-ai/asana-task-agent
I do install everything. What contains:

python 3.9.13
x64 windows Intel
env of course.


Im trying to solve problem with many configuration i always get some libraries problems.
Thats whats in :
aiohappyeyeballs                         2.4.3
aiohttp                                  3.10.10
aiosignal                                1.3.1
altair                                   5.4.1
annotated-types                          0.7.0
anthropic                                0.38.0
anyio                                    4.6.2.post1
argilla                                  2.4.0
asana                                    5.0.7
asgiref                                  3.8.1
async-timeout                            4.0.3
attrs                                    24.2.0
backoff                                  2.2.1
bcrypt                                   4.2.0
blinker                                  1.8.2
build                                    1.2.2.post1
cachetools                               5.5.0
certifi                                  2024.8.30
cffi                                     1.17.1
charset-normalizer                       3.4.0
chroma-hnswlib                           0.7.6
chromadb                                 0.5.17
click                                    8.1.7
colorama                                 0.4.6
coloredlogs                              15.0.1
cryptography                             43.0.3
dataclasses-json                         0.6.7
datasets                                 3.1.0
defusedxml                               0.7.1
Deprecated                               1.2.14
dill                                     0.3.8
distro                                   1.9.0
durationpy                               0.9
exceptiongroup                           1.2.2
fastapi                                  0.115.4
filelock                                 3.16.1
flatbuffers                              24.3.25
frozenlist                               1.5.0
fsspec                                   2024.9.0
gitdb                                    4.0.11
GitPython                                3.1.43
google-auth                              2.35.0
googleapis-common-protos                 1.65.0
greenlet                                 3.1.1
grpcio                                   1.67.1
grpcio-status                            1.48.2
h11                                      0.14.0
httpcore                                 1.0.6
httptools                                0.6.4
httpx                                    0.27.2
huggingface-hub                          0.26.2
humanfriendly                            10.0
idna                                     3.10
importlib_metadata                       8.4.0
importlib_resources                      6.4.5
Jinja2                                   3.1.4
jiter                                    0.7.0
joblib                                   1.4.2
jsonpatch                                1.33
jsonpointer                              3.0.0
jsonschema                               4.23.0
jsonschema-specifications                2024.10.1
kubernetes                               31.0.0
langchain                                0.2.6
langchain-anthropic                      0.1.16
langchain-chroma                         0.1.2
langchain-community                      0.2.6
langchain-core                           0.2.43
langchain-openai                         0.1.10
langchain-text-splitters                 0.2.4
langsmith                                0.1.139
lxml                                     5.3.0
markdown-it-py                           3.0.0
MarkupSafe                               3.0.2
marshmallow                              3.23.1
mdurl                                    0.1.2
mmh3                                     5.0.1
monotonic                                1.6
mpmath                                   1.3.0
multidict                                6.1.0
multiprocess                             0.70.16
mypy-extensions                          1.0.0
narwhals                                 1.13.1
networkx                                 3.2.1
nltk                                     3.9.1
numpy                                    1.26.4
oauthlib                                 3.2.2
onnxruntime                              1.19.2
openai                                   1.53.0
opentelemetry-api                        1.27.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-common 1.27.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc   1.27.0
opentelemetry-instrumentation            0.48b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-asgi       0.48b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-fastapi    0.48b0
opentelemetry-proto                      1.27.0
opentelemetry-sdk                        1.27.0
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions       0.48b0
opentelemetry-util-http                  0.48b0
orjson                                   3.10.11
overrides                                7.7.0
packaging                                24.1
pandas                                   2.2.3
pdfminer.six                             20221105
pdfplumber                               0.9.0
pillow                                   10.4.0
pip                                      22.0.4
posthog                                  3.7.0
propcache                                0.2.0
protobuf                                 4.25.5
pyarrow                                  18.0.0
pyasn1                                   0.6.1
pyasn1_modules                           0.4.1
pycparser                                2.22
pydantic                                 2.9.2
pydantic_core                            2.23.4
pydeck                                   0.9.1
Pygments                                 2.18.0
PyPika                                   0.48.9
pyproject_hooks                          1.2.0
pyreadline3                              3.5.4
python-dateutil                          2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv                            0.13.0
pytz                                     2024.2
PyYAML                                   6.0.2
referencing                              0.35.1
regex                                    2024.9.11
requests                                 2.32.3
requests-oauthlib                        2.0.0
requests-toolbelt                        1.0.0
rich                                     13.9.4
rpds-py                                  0.20.1
rsa                                      4.9
safetensors                              0.4.5
scikit-learn                             1.5.2
scipy                                    1.13.1
sentence-transformers                    2.2.2
sentencepiece                            0.2.0
setuptools                               58.1.0
shellingham                              1.5.4
six                                      1.16.0
smmap                                    5.0.1
sniffio                                  1.3.1
SQLAlchemy                               2.0.36
starlette                                0.41.2
streamlit                                1.36.0
sympy                                    1.13.1
tenacity                                 8.5.0
threadpoolctl                            3.5.0
tiktoken                                 0.8.0
tokenizers                               0.20.1
toml                                     0.10.2
tomli                                    2.0.2
torch                                    2.5.1
torchvision                              0.20.1
tornado                                  6.4.1
tqdm                                     4.66.6
transformers                             4.46.1
typer                                    0.12.5
typing_extensions                        4.12.2
typing-inspect                           0.9.0
tzdata                                   2024.2
unstructured                             0.3.0
urllib3                                  2.2.3
uvicorn                                  0.32.0
Wand                                     0.6.13
watchdog                                 4.0.2
watchfiles                               0.24.0
websocket-client                         1.8.0
websockets                               13.1
wrapt                                    1.16.0
xxhash                                   3.5.0
yarl                                     1.17.1
zipp                                     3.20.2

streamlit run rag-task-agent.py

  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Local URL: http://localhost:8501
  Network URL: http://192.168.1.221:8501

C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\rag-task-agent.py:47: LangChainDeprecationWarning: The class `HuggingFaceEmbeddings` was deprecated in LangChain 0.2.2 and will be removed in 0.3.0. An updated version of the class exists in the langchain-huggingface package and should be used instead. To use it run `pip install -U langchain-huggingface` and import as `from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings`.
  embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
2024-11-04 11:59:25.950 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\langchain_community\embeddings\huggingface.py", line 71, in __init__
    import sentence_transformers
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .datasets import SentencesDataset, ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\datasets\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>    
    from .ParallelSentencesDataset import ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\datasets\ParallelSentencesDataset.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .. import SentenceTransformer
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py", line 12, in <module> 
    from huggingface_hub import HfApi, HfFolder, Repository, hf_hub_url, cached_download
ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_download' from 'huggingface_hub' (C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 589, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\rag-task-agent.py", line 52, in <module>
    db = get_chroma_instance()
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\caching\cache_utils.py", line 168, in wrapper     
    return cached_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\caching\cache_utils.py", line 197, in __call__    
    return self._get_or_create_cached_value(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\caching\cache_utils.py", line 224, in _get_or_create_cached_value
    return self._handle_cache_miss(cache, value_key, func_args, func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\caching\cache_utils.py", line 280, in _handle_cache_miss
    computed_value = self._info.func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\rag-task-agent.py", line 47, in get_chroma_instance
    embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\_api\deprecation.py", line 215, in warn_if_direct_instance
    return wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\langchain_community\embeddings\huggingface.py", line 74, in __init__
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not import sentence_transformers python package. Please install it with `pip install sentence-transformers`.
2024-11-04 11:59:26.496 Examining the path of torch.classes raised: Tried to instantiate class '__path__._path', but it does not exist! Ensure that it is registered via torch::class_
2024-11-04 11:59:38.355 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\langchain_community\embeddings\huggingface.py", line 71, in __init__
    import sentence_transformers
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .datasets import SentencesDataset, ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\datasets\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>    
    from .ParallelSentencesDataset import ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\datasets\ParallelSentencesDataset.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .. import SentenceTransformer
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py", line 12, in <module> 
    from huggingface_hub import HfApi, HfFolder, Repository, hf_hub_url, cached_download
ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_download' from 'huggingface_hub' (C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 589, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\rag-task-agent.py", line 52, in <module>
    db = get_chroma_instance()
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\caching\cache_utils.py", line 168, in wrapper     
    return cached_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\caching\cache_utils.py", line 197, in __call__    
    return self._get_or_create_cached_value(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\caching\cache_utils.py", line 224, in _get_or_create_cached_value
    return self._handle_cache_miss(cache, value_key, func_args, func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\caching\cache_utils.py", line 280, in _handle_cache_miss
    computed_value = self._info.func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\rag-task-agent.py", line 47, in get_chroma_instance
    embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\_api\deprecation.py", line 215, in warn_if_direct_instance
    return wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\langchain_community\embeddings\huggingface.py", line 74, in __init__
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not import sentence_transformers python package. Please install it with `pip install sentence-transformers`.
2024-11-04 11:59:38.805 Examining the path of torch.classes raised: Tried to instantiate class '__path__._path', but it does not exist! Ensure that it is registered via torch::class_

Explain it to me please, im trying every possible way, and it seems i miss something.
Perhaps requirments file is from some old project? Difficult to say


I tried many combinations with libraries, not every for sure.
Run the code and understand what's going on

have you tried what the message suggests? "An updated version of the class exists in the langchain-huggingface package and should be used instead. To use it run `pip install -...."

Looking at your traceback, we can see that it's not actually that sentence_transformers isn't installed, since it's running code in "C:\Users\alute\Desktop\ASANAGPT\ASANAGPT4\asana-task-agent\env39\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers. What's happening is that an ImportError occurs inside sentence_tranformers, which is being caught Could not import sentence_transformers python package message.
So, what is the actual error? Digging further, it seems like the cached_download() function was removed from huggingface_hub in version 0.26.0. Since you have 0.26.2, that is most likely the issue. I would try running
pip install huggingface_hub<0.26.0

and taking it from there (at least until sentence_transformers updates with support for newer versions of huggingface_hub).
